# asp.net maintain scroll bar position after postback in iis 8 and win server 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-8

I have a page with update panel on it. Everything works find in my local (vs 2010, iis 7, win 7). But after I moved my project to server (vs 2010, iis 8, win server 2012), this page keep scroll to the top after partial postback. I have tried both maintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true and javascript, but those don't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net standard methods:

```
   <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" /> //in web config

    <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %> //in page declaration

    System.Web.UI.Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true; //in code
```

doesn't work with partial rendering.

Maybe [this link](http://www.nullskull.com/a/774/aspnet-ajax-maintain-scroll-position-from-a-partial-page-update.aspx) helps you.